# How to extract elements from a list of tuples in python for a ReportLab table?

Tags: python, reportlab

I have a problem with creating a reportlab table containing elements from a list of tuples.

Having the input:

`meta= [('#Instances (Test)', '250'), ('#Instances (Train)', '250')]`

I intuitively thought of writing it that way:

```
for key, value in meta:
    data = [['Solver', '%s'%(solver_name)],
             ['%s'%(key), '%s'%(value)],
              ['%s'%(key), '%s'%(value)]]
meta_data = Table(data, colWidths=None, rowHeights=None, style=None, splitByRow=1,
                  repeatRows=0, repeatCols=0)
```

But it only considers the last tuple making `('#Instances (Train)', '250')` appear in both rows.
Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: In your loop, you always replace the whole `data` with the structure you wrote there, and that structure has two times the same key-value pair, so of course  `data` ends up looking like that with the last values looped over. You see what I mean? I doesn't matter how many items you have in your `meta`, you still end up with that structure having two key-value pairs with the same info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only getting the last `key, value` from your input because every time in the loop you are changing the whole `data` variable. What you have meant is propably this

```
data = []
for key, value in meta:
    data.append([['Solver', solver_name],[key, value]])
meta_data = Table(data, colWidths=None, rowHeights=None, style=None, \
  splitByRow=1,repeatRows=0, repeatCols=0)
```

In the above code, I initialize `data` variable as an empty list, then go through each tuple in meta, assigning that `tuple[0]` as `key` and `tuple[1]` as `value`. The only thing that is done with those variables is we append them to the list we initialized at the start.

Comment: Don't worry mate, it happens to everyone once in a while :)